# snakemake stops with no error using dynamic

Tags: snakemake

I experience something strange using snakemake. Here is a simple example to show you the problem.
The following snakefile works (sample1.txt and sample2.txt being any small text file) :
[image: working_dag]

```
samples = ['sample1','sample2']

rule end:
    input:
        merged = expand("{sample}_merged.txt", sample=samples)
        
rule blocking:
    output:
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 'blocking' >  {output.blocking_input}"
    
rule split:
    input:
        text_file = "{sample}.txt",
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    output:    
        splitted_file = dynamic("{sample}_cut_{part}")
    params: 
        prefix = "{sample}_cut_"
    shell:
        "split -l 3 {input.text_file} {params.prefix}" 
        
rule rename: 
    input:
        splitted_file = "{sample}_cut_{part}"
    output:
        renamed = "{sample}_renamed_{part}"
    shell:
        "mv {input.splitted_file} {output.renamed}"
        
rule merge: 
    input:
        splitted_file = dynamic("{sample}_renamed_{part}")
    output:
        merged = "{sample}_merged.txt"
    params: 
        prefix = "{sample}_renamed_"
    shell:
        "cat {params.prefix}* > {output.merged}"
```

But if I need the file "blocking_file.txt" for the rule `rename`, then the workflow doesn't create this file and stops without any error:

```
samples = ['sample1','sample2']

rule end:
    input:
        merged = expand("{sample}_merged.txt", sample=samples)
        
rule blocking:
    output:
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 'blocking' >  {output.blocking_input}"
    
rule split:
    input:
        text_file = "{sample}.txt"
    output:    
        splitted_file = dynamic("{sample}_cut_{part}")
    params: 
        prefix = "{sample}_cut_"
    shell:
        "split -l 3 {input.text_file} {params.prefix}" 
        
rule rename: 
    input:
        splitted_file = "{sample}_cut_{part}",
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    output:
        renamed = "{sample}_renamed_{part}"
    shell:
        "mv {input.splitted_file} {output.renamed}"
        
rule merge: 
    input:
        splitted_file = dynamic("{sample}_renamed_{part}")
    output:
        merged = "{sample}_merged.txt"
    params: 
        prefix = "{sample}_renamed_"
    shell:
        "cat {params.prefix}* > {output.merged}"
```

```
[]$ workflow : snakemake -s bug_block.rules -c1
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job         count    min threads    max threads
--------  -------  -------------  -------------
blocking        1              1              1
end             1              1              1
merge           2              1              1
rename          2              1              1
split           2              1              1
total           8              1              1

Select jobs to execute...

[Thu Jul 22 17:08:14 2021]
rule split:
    input: sample2.txt
    output: sample2_cut_{*} (dynamic)
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: sample=sample2
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Subsequent jobs will be added dynamically depending on the output of this job
Dynamically updating jobs
[Thu Jul 22 17:08:14 2021]
Finished job 7.
1 of 11 steps (9%) done
Select jobs to execute...

[Thu Jul 22 17:08:14 2021]
rule split:
    input: sample1.txt
    output: sample1_cut_{*} (dynamic)
    jobid: 3
    wildcards: sample=sample1
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Subsequent jobs will be added dynamically depending on the output of this job
Dynamically updating jobs
[Thu Jul 22 17:08:14 2021]
Finished job 3.
2 of 13 steps (15%) done
Complete log: ...
```

The DAG looks OK to me.
[image]

Thanks to your suggestion, I manage to make it run using checkpoint:

```
samples = ['sample1','sample2']

rule final_output:
    input:
        merged = expand("{sample}_merged.txt", sample=samples)

# split each file into several ones

checkpoint split:
    input:
        text_file = "{sample}.txt"
    output:    
        directory("{sample}_split")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output}
        split -l 3 {input.text_file} {output}/   ## / IS necessary
        """
        

# add extra file
rule blocking:
    output:
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 'blocking' >  {output.blocking_input}"


# rename these unknown number of files

rule rename: 
    input:
        splitted_file = "{sample}_split/{i}",
        blocking_input = "blocking_file.txt"
    output:
        renamed = "{sample}_renamed_{i}"
    shell:
        """
        sleep 2s
        mv {input.splitted_file} {output.renamed}
        """
         
        
# merge them together into one file per sample:

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.split.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("{{sample}}_renamed_{i}",
           i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, '{i}')).i)
    
        
rule merge: 
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        merged = "{sample}_merged.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output.merged}"
```

I'm not sure if I use the wildcards properly and if the function aggregate_input is the best way to do it. I also wonder if it possible to avoid creating a directory for the output in the checkpoint. I tried the format `{sample}_split_{i}` but couldn't make it run.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, feel free to accept it to show others that the problem has been solved satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn `rule split` into `checkpoint split` for this to work. Have a look at the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution):

```yaml
checkpoint split:
    input:
        text_file = "{sample}.txt"
    output:    
        splitted_file = dynamic("{sample}_cut_{part}")
    params: 
        prefix = "{sample}_cut_"
    shell:
        "split -l 3 {input.text_file} {params.prefix}"
```

I'm also not sure whether dynamic may not be deprecated. At least this entry in the [changelog](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=dynamic&check_keywords=yes&area=default) makes it look like it may be. There's not a single example for dynamic in the documentation.